# Gray smoke went black and then impossible to start the engine

Tags: ford, starting, smoke, fiesta

I just had a breakdown of my car, I was driving on the highway at 120km / h  for about 15 or 20 minutes when I saw gray smoke emerging behind from the rear, I stopped right away, when I came out of the car, the smoke went black and the engine stopped immediately after.

After that, it was impossible to start the engin again :(

Do you guys know what can be the cause?

I have a 2010 Ford Fiesta.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does the engine still turn over?

Comment: No, i hear  a noise when I try but i can't get it to turn on

Comment: What kind of noise? A click? A grinding? A whirr?

Comment: @David it tries to start but doesn't, i would say a whirr

Comment: A whirr might be the starter, but we don't know if the starter is turning the engine or not, and so we can't isolate the starter assembly as the problem. The earlier smoke suggests an engine or head gasket or fueling issue. Remote diagnosis is difficult. I think you need to put the vehicle in the hands of a mechanic to find out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a full diagnostic of my car, and it was the engine, i have to change the engine now.

To the others who might uncounter the same probleme, if you see smoke emerging from the rear, and hear the engine going crazy, pull off right away and stop the engine, it might save you a couple hundreds of dollars.

Comment: Engines dont just "go crazy". What really happened? Was it a runaway diesel engine or was the enigne running without any engine oil?